# Values read via fscanf() not printing out

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to print out the first 3 line from a text file.

```
states 10
start  0
accept 9
```

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");   
    printf("File is open successfully.\n");
    char *ptr, buf[256];
    int states; //states
    int start; //start
    int accept; //accept

    while((ptr = fgets(buf, 256, fp)) != NULL){
        printf("%s", ptr);
        //process this line from the file
    }
    printf("============================\n");
    char s1[100], s2[100], s3[100];
    fscanf("%s %i",s1, &states);
    fscanf("%s %i",s2, &start);
    fscanf("%s %i",s3, &accept);
    printf("states: %i\n start: %i\n accpet: %i\n", states, start, accept);
}
```

The output I am receiving:

```
states: 32528
start: -29575952
accpet: 32767
```

After printing out the what's in the file. and prints out the random number, I cannot seem to get the states, start, and accept number.

Thanks.

Comment: The calls to `fscanf()` miss to pass `fp`!

Comment: Also checking the outcome of (relevant) system calls helps during the debugging phase and makes production code more stable.

Comment: @alk, I tried to put fp, the output is still incorrect.

Comment: You need the `fseek` call as well.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a good problem descrition. Is there a compilation error? Don't you get the expected output? Does it crash?

Comment: @MOehm: The incorrect output it given in the question.

Comment: @FredLarson: I know. I referred to the OP's comment, not the question. (Should have made that clear, though.)

Comment: @MOehm, I edited. I got it all sorted out.

Comment: @user4127382: You edited the question to correct the problem, thereby invalidating the answer that was already posted. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't use fscanf properly.  The first argument should be file descriptor:

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

you can see usage (for example) at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm

Comment: That's part of the problem. Fixing this won't completely solve it. `fp` is still at EOF.

Comment: Agree. fseek is required.

Comment: The OP edited the code in the question to fix that problem. Apparently there was still another problem.

Comment: As mentioned before - fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET) should be called after  while loop